# chmod syntax in FTP-Client on all subdirectories

Tags: ftp, chmod, subdirectory

Which ftp client or which syntax allows easy chmod for sub-directories?

Answer (score 1):

LFTP allows for recursive CHMOD if the client allows it. You can accomplish this by logging in with LFTP from a Unix/Linux CLI and then run the following:

```
chmod -R 0755 /www/directory/*
```

You could also setup a real nifty Bash script for this:

```
#!/bin/bash
lftp <<EOF
set ftp:ssl-allow no
set ftp:passive-mode true
set ftp:list-options -a
open -u [user],[password] [host]
chmod -R 0777 /www/directory/*
EOF
```

Of course LFTP does not distinguish between files and folders, for running this command on only files/folders respectively I would suggest using FileZilla. It allows this when running the command on a folder.

Answer (score 0):

To chmod all subdirs from where you are (recursive):

```
chmod -R *
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) does it

Answer (score 0):

[ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com/) will support the `chmod` command if the FTP Server supports it.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer from @Ken G suggests, this is more likely to be a question of "what does the FTP server support".

I tried ncftp (running under Cygwin on Win XP) against Sun FTP running on Solaris 10 (where `chmod -R` is supported by the o/s version of `chmod`).  I got an error back:

```
ncftp /work1/jleffler/tmp > chmod -R g+x *
chmod g+x: server said: 'SITE CHMOD -R g+x': command not understood.
chmod *: server said: 'SITE CHMOD -R xx.pl': command not understood.
ncftp /work1/jleffler/tmp >
```

My suspicion is that few if any systems make it easy.  It would be worth checking out whether the NCFTP server helps you.

Answer (score 0):

```
chmod -R 755 {DIR}
```

You recurse with -R